# BFS/DFS Web Crawler

Tags: python, performance, web-scraping, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search

I've built a web crawler that starts at an origin URL and crawls the web using a BFS or DFS method.  Everything is working fine, but the performance is horrendous.  I think the major cause of this is my use of synchronous requests. I've used BeautifulSoup and the Requests library to implement this, so nothing is happening asynchronously.

I've tried using AsyncIO and a couple other ways of making this async, but it's given me a lot of trouble.  Any advice on how to do so, or other recommendations for improving performance would be much appreciated.

**BFS Usage:**

```
python3 Webcrawler.py [origin_url] BFS [#_nodes_to_crawl] 0 [keyword_to_find]
```

**DFS Usage:**

```
python3 Webcrawler.py [origin_url]] DFS [#_nodes_to_crawl] [depth_limit] [keyword_to_find]
```

**Webcrawler.py**

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import collections
from Graph import Graph
from Node import Node
import sys
from time import gmtime, strftime
from timeout import timeout
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import Process
import json
import pdb

class WebCrawler:
    def __init__(self, originUrl, method, totalNodes, depthLimit=None, keyword=None):
        self.originUrl = originUrl
        self.method = method
        self.totalNodes = int(totalNodes)
        self.nodeCount = 0
        self.depthLimit = int(depthLimit)
        self.currentDepth = 0
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.keywordUrls = []
        self.nodeUrlMap = {}
        self.nodesToVisit = []
        self.visitedUrls = set()
        self.graph = Graph()
        self.nodeIndex = 0
        self.storeCookie()
        originTitle = self.getTitle(originUrl)
        startNode = Node(originUrl, None, originTitle)
        self.crawl(startNode)

    def crawl(self, node):
        print("crawl(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        visited = node.url in self.visitedUrls
        if not visited:
            self.graph.addNode(node, self.nodeIndex)
            self.nodeIndex += 1
            self.nodeCount += 1
            self.visitedUrls.add(node.url)
        if node.sourceNodes: # If this is not the starting node
            sourceNode = node.sourceNodes.pop()
            if sourceNode.index is not None and node.index is not None:
                self.graph.addEdge(sourceNode.index, node.index) # Add an edge between sourceNode and node
        if not visited:
            soup = self.generateSoup(node.url)
            hasKeyword = self.checkForKeyword(soup, node.url)
            if hasKeyword:
                node.keyword = True
            links = self.findLinks(soup)
            links = self.validLinks(links)
            links = {l for l in links} # Remove duplicate links
            if links:
                if self.method == "BFS":
                    self.bfs(node, links)
                else: # DFS
                    self.currentDepth += 1
                    if self.currentDepth >= self.depthLimit: # If depth limit reached, getNextNode (up a level)
                        self.currentDepth = 0 # Reset currentDepth
                        self.getNextNode()
                    else: # Otherwise, keep going deeper
                        self.dfs(node, links)
            else: # No links present
                self.getNextNode()
        else: # Avoid infinite loop
            self.getNextNode()

    def validLinks(self, links):
        print("validLinks(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        validLinks = []
        for link in links:
            # Only add links while there is still room
            if self.nodeCount + len(validLinks) <= self.totalNodes:
                if self.isValidUrl(link):
                    validLinks.append(link)
        return validLinks

    def isValidUrl(self, url):
        print("isValidUrl(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        extensionBlacklist = ["zip", "dmg", "msi", "tar", "exe", "sisx"]
        for x in extensionBlacklist:
            if x in url:
                return False
        if "http" not in url: return False
        parsed_url = urlparse(url)
        if not bool(parsed_url.scheme): return False
        try:
            self.testRequest(url)
        except:
            return False
        return True

    @timeout(3)
    def testRequest(self, url):
        requests.get(url)

    def getNextNode(self):
        print("getNextNode(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        if len(self.nodesToVisit) is not 0 and not self.nodeLimitReached():
            # We use the same data structure to store urlsToVisit for BFS and DFS,
            # and pop elements off the same way.  How the elements are added is
            # what's important.
            nextNode = self.nodesToVisit.pop()
            self.crawl(nextNode)
        else: # Crawl is over
            self.printGraph()

    def printGraph(self):
        for node in self.graph.nodes:
            print("\nNode:")
            if node.title:
                print("Index: " + str(node.index))
                print("Title: " + node.title)
                print("URL: " + node.url)
                print("Keyword: " + str(node.keyword))
        if self.graph.edges:
            print("\nEdges:")
            edgeCount = 0
            for e in self.graph.edges:
                print("Source: " + str(e.source) + " Target: " + str(e.target))
        if self.keywordUrls:
            print("\nKeyword URLs:")
            for k in self.keywordUrls:
                print("URL: " + k)
        print("\nJSON:")
        print(self.jsonSerialize())

    def jsonSerialize(self):
        for n in self.graph.nodes:
            n.sourceNodes = []
        self.graph.edges = list(self.graph.edges)
        return json.dumps(self.graph, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)

    def storeCookie(self):
        # Store graph as cookie (do this one)
        pass

    def nodeLimitReached(self):
        return self.nodeCount >= self.totalNodes

    # Convert URL into soup
    def generateSoup(self, url):
        print("generateSoup(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
        return soup

    # Parse soup to find links
    def findLinks(self, soup):
        print("findLinks(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        links = soup.findAll('a')
        hrefs = []
        for link in links:
            href = link.get('href', '')
            hrefs.append(href)
        return hrefs

    def getTitle(self, url):
        print("getTitle(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        soup = self.generateSoup(url)
        titles = soup.findAll('title')
        if titles:
            title = str(titles[0]).replace("<title>", "")
            title = title.replace("</title>", "")
            return title

    def bfs(self, currentNode, links):
        print("bfs(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        for link in links:
            # If url is not already visited, and nodesToVisit+nodeCount hasn't exceeded totalNodes
            if link not in self.visitedUrls and self.nodeCount + len(self.nodesToVisit) <= self.totalNodes:
                title = self.getTitle(link)
                newNode = Node(link, [currentNode], title)
                newNode.sourceNodes.insert(0, currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.insert(0, newNode)
                self.nodeUrlMap[link] = newNode
            elif link in self.nodeUrlMap: # Repeat URL, get existing node
                existingNode = self.nodeUrlMap[link]
                existingNode.sourceNodes.insert(0, currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.insert(0, existingNode)
        self.getNextNode()

    def dfs(self, currentNode, links):
        print("dfs(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
        for link in links:
            if link not in self.visitedUrls:
                title = self.getTitle(link)
                newNode = Node(link, [currentNode], title)
                newNode.sourceNodes.append(currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.append(newNode)
            elif link in self.nodeUrlMap: # Repeat URL, get existing node
                existingNode = self.nodeUrlMap[link]
                existingNode.sourceNodes.append(currentNode)
                self.nodesToVisit.append(existingNode)
        self.getNextNode()

    def checkForKeyword(self, soup, url):
        # If keyword found in soup, append url to keywordUrls
        if soup.body and soup.body.findAll(text=self.keyword):
            self.keywordUrls.append(url)
            return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    webCrawler = WebCrawler(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3], sys.argv[4], sys.argv[5])
```

**Graph.py**

```
from Edge import Edge

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes=[], edges=set()):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.edges = edges

    def addNode(self, node, nodeIndex):
        node.index = nodeIndex
        self.nodes.append(node)

    def addEdge(self, sourceNodeIdx, targetNodeIdx):
        edge = Edge(sourceNodeIdx, targetNodeIdx)
        self.edges.add(edge)
```

**Node.py**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, url, sourceNodes, title, index=None):
        self.index = index
        self.url = url
        self.sourceNodes = sourceNodes
        self.title = title
        self.keyword = False
```

**Edge.py**

```
class Edge:
    def __init__(self, source, target):
        self.source = source
        self.target = target

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.source == other.source and self.target == other.target

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.source, self.target))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "performance is horrendous"? You wouldn't happen to be trying to crawl the entire web are you? Also your dfs looks a lot like bfs

Comment: @smac89 If you would like a quantitative answer, 22 seconds for 20 nodes using BFS, and 1 minute using DFS (roughly).  And no I'm obviously not trying to crawl the entire internet, I'm not an idiot, but I would like to be able to do more than a few nodes without having to stop for a lunch break.  And the only real difference between BFS and DFS is the use of a stack vs. a queue, so yes, they look similar.

Comment: TBH that's not bad...22 seconds for 20 nodes means about 1 second per request. I think you are fighting something more than just your algorithm not being fast enough. Have you considered that maybe your network speed is probably what is holding you back? Also DFS explores until it can't anymore, so 1 minute for DFS for 20 nodes could also mean that it takes DFS 3 seconds to completely explore an edge leading from a given node. You could probably look into changing DNS server, or if you are on wi-fi, then try using direct Ethernet connection and see how performance is affected

Comment: @smac89 The growth is not linear however.  100 nodes takes like 5 minutes for BFS.  You're right that the network connection is a limiting factor, but a large portion of the time is spent on verifying a URL is valid before crawling it.  My thought was that I could check all the URL's on a given page asynchronously and that would significantly improve the time spent validating those links.  See `isValidUrl` for what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand your bottlenecks by profiling and measuring your program, but here are some **performance notes** after a "static" look at your code:

- try out the [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](https://scrapy.org/) - it is of an asynchronous nature (based on `twisted` library) and has a very rich functionality for close to everything you may need for web-scraping
- initialize [`requests.Session()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and reuse:

  > if you're making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
  >   connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
  >   performance increase
- switch from `html.parser` to a faster `lxml`:

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "lxml")
  ```
- use [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots) for the `Graph`, `Node` and `Edge` classes
- switch from `json` to the faster [`ujson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson)
- the "test request"'s speed may be improved by switching from `GET` to `HEAD` (using the `head()` method instead of `get()`)

**Code style notes:**

- unused and not properly organized imports ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))
- Python naming convention ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions))

**Other notes:**

- looks like you are not properly handling relative and absolute URLs while extracting the links, here is a [sample how to handle both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631314/771848)
- I don't believe your "extension black list" check is good enough - currently, you are checking for a prohibited extension to be present anywhere in the url, which will mark a lot of "valid" URLs as "invalid"
- the `getTitle` can be improved by using a [`find()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) and checking the result to be not `None`, then, if a tag is found, use [`get_text()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get the text of a tag:

  ```
  def getTitle(self, url):
      print("getTitle(): " + strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime()))
      soup = self.generateSoup(url)
      title = soup.title  # same as soup.find("title")
      if title is not None:
          return title.get_text()
  ```
- the `checkForKeyword()` would only return `True` if there is a text node that matches the keyword exactly. E.g., if a keyword is `test`, `checkForKeyword()` would return `False` if `test` is there in the HTML, but is a part of a text node, say:

  ```
  <b>It is important to test your code<b>
  ```
- switching to [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) may improve overall usability, robustness and readability of command-line argument parsing

There are other things to improve, but I hope you will get more reviews. Or/And, you can approach it step-by-step making the code better (very broad term, I understand) on every "iteration".